# Children are not visible in the deeper level of categories in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

After level 3 of category in shopware 6, the children are not visible or coming into the storefront. Visible value is true for all the categories created. Child count is showing but visibleChildCount is 0.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer. It is the settings in the saleschannel. You need to increase the navigation level to get more categories inside the navigation.
[image]